# Bookmarked questions - how to see them?

Tags: support

After bookmarking a couple of questions, how do I show a list of all questions bookmarked by me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just visit your profile and choose the bookmarks tab

> [image]

or click here https://askubuntu.com/users/current/?tab=bookmarks